# Information on "stronger form" of Dirichlet's Theorem on Arithmetic Progressions

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers

From Wikipedia:

"Stronger forms of Dirichlet's theorem state that, for any arithmetic progression, the sum of the reciprocals of the prime numbers in the progression diverges."

Can anyone direct me to a proof  of this "stronger" fact, or a paper that discusses it? Thanks.

Comment: The standard proof of Dirichlet's theorem proves this.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan : good point, just scanned a couple of the standard proofs online. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a proof in Serre's *A Course in Arithmetic*, chapter 6.